# vim/nvim not filling windows terminal

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I'm runing nvim through wsl2 on ubuntu. However if I use the windows terminal nvim or vim will not fill the whole terminal

[image]

How can I get rid of those black borders?

It works just fine if I use the Ubuntu terminal. But I'd prefer to use the Windows Terminal
[image]

Comment: From the images I honestly cannot see the problem you mention.

Comment: I edited the first screenshot with arrows to make it more clear.

Comment: ah ok thanks I see it now

Comment: What does your profile for this shell look like in `settings.json`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your profile in `settings.json` add this:
`"padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0"`

Comment: For the lazy, `"padding": "0"` also works.

Answer (score 7):

With `"padding": "0"` I still got the black bar on the right, to get rid of it set `"scrollbarState": "hidden"`

Answer (score 7):

Actually，I set `"padding": "0"` and `scrollbarState": "hidden"`.

[image: It shows here.]

There is still a distance at the bottom of Windows terminal where the content is never displayed.

Answer (score 4):

It occured to me recently, but I found a way to deal with it. 
Open the `settings.json` and then add `"padding": "0, 0, 0, -3",`.

At least it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the "-3", didn't realise you could have negative values and this got rid of the extra padding at the bottom of the screen for me!

Comment: @DannyHerbert I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Font size was the issue for me. I had increased it to '14' from the default '12' but changed it back to '12' and the gaps on the right and bottom are now gone.

Answer (score 1):

For me very interesting configuration helped))

1. I am using windows terminal with Nerd Fonrs and with default font size 14px
2. I am using windows with such screen settings

[image]

I've added next to terminal settings.json (see padding property)

[image]

After that I still have some paddings, which removed with zoom in or out (ctrl + or ctrl -), once I am zoom in or zoom out twice, padding removed.

I guess, it also could be remove by changing the display settings or font size.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be an issue with NVim. The Windows Terminal simply has padding on all the sides of the terminal window, to get rid of it adjust the padding in the terminal `settings.json` file. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#text-settings) is a breakdown of all the text configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Terminal Preview

1. Go to `Settings > Profiles > YOUR_TERMINAL > APPEARANCE`
2. Set Padding to `0`
3. Set Scrollbar Visibility `hidden`
4. Hit save.

Like so:

[image: Windows Terminal Ubuntu Profile]